# embed Flex components into Java Swing

Tags: java, apache-flex

I'm going to embed Flex components into Java app, just embedding swf into JFrame. Does anybody know how to use EZ JCOM ? I don't know what is Flash COM or Flash ActiveX. please help me

Answer (score 0):

Im working on a swing app that does exactly the same, i have a firefox instance embebbed on a swing app. For that iam using the following library, check it out [The DJ Project](http://djproject.sourceforge.net/main/index.html)